# Upload CSV file into SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am curently trying to upload a CSV file into a sql table, but I don't want to upload the first line which contains the name of every column value that will be inserted. I used a variable c to count the number of rows that will be inserted. For the first line c=0 so I used a condition to upload the values from the row only if c!==0, but it stil uploades the values from the first line.

My code looks like this:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$c = 0;
if ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=='application/vnd.ms-excel')
{
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 3000, ",")) !== false)
    {
        $tid = trim($filesop[0]);
        $beneficiar = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[1])));
        $locatie = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[2])));
        $localitate = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[3])));
        $judet = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[4])));
        $adresa = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[5])));
        $model = trim($filesop[6]);

        $qry = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM beneficiari WHERE `nume` = '".$beneficiar."'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
            $id_client=$row['id'];
        }

        $qry_id_model=mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM modele WHERE `model` = '".$model."'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_id_model)){
            $id_model=$row['id'];
        }

        $adresa1 = $adresa.",".$localitate;

        if ($c!==0){
            $sql = mysql_query(
                "INSERT INTO pos_equipments_other 
                     (id_client, model, tid, beneficiar, adresa, agentie, judet) 
                 VALUES 
                     ('$id_client','$id_model','$tid','$beneficiar','$adresa1',
                      '$locatie','$judet')"
            );
        }

        $c = $c + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop using [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql-query). The mysql extension was deprecated years ago and has been removed from PHP. See [the manual for choosing a newer API to talk to your MySQL database in PHP](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing) instead.

Comment: stop using `mysqli_query()` combined with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and post a small sample of the csv file including the headers, the first 4-5 lines should be sufficient

Comment: You should not insert rows based on just the line number. Instead you should validate the data (is the `$id_client` valid, are rows found, etc.) and insert based on that. Using a prepared statement.

Comment: The first part of the indexed array is header row so just skip over it!

Comment: But the simplest way would be to use MySQL's `load data infile` command to import a csv file...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html